# Could we connect one crystal capacitor to power and another to ground?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, pcb-design, crystal

There is a 12MHz HC49 package crystal which according to [TLV320AIC23B](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/spraaj2/spraaj2.pdf?ts=1649590667897&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTLV320AIC23B) needs two 22pF capacitors to ground.

In the picture below, I can't connect both crystal pins by capaitor to ground.  I can connect C1 to ground but C2 to Vdd. Is that a good right workaround, or must it be connected to ground?

[image]

Guys told in comment's you can easily avoid this ground shortage situation by some routing affort. This is accepted and I've placed my crystal entirely on top of U1, but generally I'm couries if this is possible or not?

Comment: Why do you say you can't connect it to ground. Yes you can. You can e.g. move C1 next to C2, or route VDD as narrow trace under C1. And your question cannot be answered because we don't know which MCU you have. In some MCU oscillator circuits it was even mandatory to connect both caps to VDD due to how the MCU works. And in some circuits it was recommended to have four crystal caps, two to VDD and two to GND. But it is likely that your MCU requires caps to GND and there is no way to know if other configurations are supported, unless you ask the MCU manufacturer, and likely they suggest GND.

Comment: You might also reroute the trace going to pin 1 of the crystal right through the center of the round pad, giving an extra mm or so on the left. Then slide the two small diagonal segments to the left of pin 1 further to the left, this might give yet another mm or so.  All that might give room to reposition the component above the crystal and then reposition one or both small caps.

Comment: @Justme As question update IC is TLV320AIC23B. Yes that's possible, I didn't mind! I have no problem with placing them two next to each other. But how to sure that small Vdd trace degrade IC performance(I know this is another question). But the general question is still, and I'm curious about that.

Comment: You really should have a groundplane otherwise I suspect your circuit will be rather noisy. Not good considering you have an audio adc in there.

Comment: @Kartman Does simply making other side of board, ground, will magically remedy the noise pollution?

Comment: @Nedd Thanks. .

Comment: Proper pcb layout cures many ills.